# Is this a case of shared memory?

Tags: python, optimization, parallel-processing, race-condition, joblib

I'm trying to optimize the following loop:

```
telePortMatrix = sparse.coo_matrix(self.matrix,dtype=float)
telePortMatrixCSR = telePortMatrix.tocsr()

for r in telePortMatrix.row:
    rowCount = telePortMatrix.getrow(r).nnz
    rowSum = telePortMatrix.getrow(r).sum()
    avg = rowSum/rowCount
    for c in telePortMatrix.col:
        if telePortMatrixCSR[r,c] != 0:
            telePortMatrixCSR[r,c] = avg
```

with the `joblib` module:

```
telePortMatrix = sparse.coo_matrix(self.matrix,dtype=float)
telePortMatrixCSR = telePortMatrix.tocsr()

def loop(r):
    rowCount = telePortMatrix.getrow(r).nnz
    rowSum = telePortMatrix.getrow(r).sum()
    avg = rowSum/rowCount
    for c in telePortMatrix.col:
        if telePortMatrixCSR[r,c] != 0:
            telePortMatrixCSR[r,c] = avg

Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(loop)(i) for i in telePortMatrix.row)
```

But according to the [Shared-memory semantics](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html#shared-memory-semantics) section of the documentation, if the parallel function really needs to rely on the shared memory semantics of threads, it should be made explicit with `require='sharedmem'`. I'm not quite sure if this is the case of shared memory.

Since we're using the same matrix but not a single function call will access the same row twice.

Comment: Writing in parallel into CSR matrix is a bad idea as this can cause *race condition*. In your specific case, it may not be the case if `avg` is ensured to not be 0 (which seems the case), but I am not sure Scipy allow safe parallel accesses in this case. I think this is much safer to work directly on the compressed representation of CSR matrix (as NUmpy arrays) for this computation.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, can you please clarify how would it cause _race condition_ if avg was 0 ? If those parallel execution would be called with different value of r each time, they won't be writing in the same index I think.

Comment: The sparse-matrix CSR format is *compressed*. Thus, switching a non zero value to a zero value (or the reverse operation) can change the internal data structure in a way that is incompatible with the parallel accesses. This is totally dependant of the internal CSR representation used (ie. implementation dependant), but I think is should be just 3 flatten Numpy arrays internally.